# Transformation of model

Tags: regression, self-study, generalized-linear-model, modeling, generalized-least-squares

I have the following model

> $y_i=\beta_1+\beta_2x_i+\epsilon_i$ with $E(\epsilon^2)=\sigma^2\exp(x_i)$

And I have to use the proper transformation to obtain a model where the variance of the error is $\sigma^2$.

**My guess**:

I do not have any guesses because I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: This looks like a homework problem, largely because you'll never have such precise information on the conditional heteroskedasticity IRL.  If self-study, you should tag as such.

Comment: My physics advisor used to say that what's not an exponent is a logarithm

Comment: I finally got it. It was, contructing the model with matrices, such as $y=X\beta+\epsilon$, "transform" it by multiplying by $K^{-1}$ (such as $V=K'K=KK$) from the left, and renaming (almost) everything you arrive at $z=B\beta+g$, and make $Var(g)=Var(K^{-1}\epsilon)=K^{-1}Var(\epsilon)K^{-1}=\sigma^2K^{-1} V K^{-1}$. So if you make $K=diag(exp^{-1}(x_i))$ you got it.

Comment: Feel free to write the answer if you want, and I'll mark it as correct. (Or I'll do it later)

Comment: That was a hard way to do it!  Moreover, it was so complicated you did not get a correct answer: if you divide $y_i$ by $\exp(x_i)$, then the error term will be $\epsilon_i\exp(-x_i)$, whence its variance will be $\operatorname{Var}(\epsilon_i\exp(-x_i)) = \exp(-x_i)^2\operatorname{Var}(\epsilon_i) = \exp(-x_i)\sigma^2.$ You also should be explicit about the assumption $E(\epsilon)=0$, for otherwise these calculations need adjustment.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably replace "I have no idea" in the question with at least some outline of the way that you understand now how to proceed, since it shows (presumably) some form of research along the lines we'd expect to give guidance.

Since you show in comments that you already have the right idea (but you make it harder than it needs to be for this case -- you don't need matrices for this simple version of the problem), let me discuss a slightly more general case (generalizing the form of $\epsilon$) in a simpler way -- but without quite giving *all* the details of showing it does what's needed. It essentially proceeds as you were doing with the matrix-formulation.

Let $y_i = \beta_0+\beta_1 x_i + \epsilon_i$ where the $\epsilon$'s are all mutually independent with mean $0$, and $\text{Var}(\epsilon_i) = \sigma^2 v(x_i)$ for $v$ some specified function where $v(x)\geq 0$ for all possible $x$.

(This can be fitted by weighted regression as it stands. Simply supply $w_i = 1/v(x_i)$ as weights to a regression routine, though note that you'll need $v$ strictly greater than $0$ to do this -- as you will for the approach below; observations where $v$ is exactly $0$ can still be done if there's no more than $2$ of them; and if there's more than $1$ of them the rest of the data can have no impact.)

However, it can be converted to an unweighted regression --

Define $s(x)=v(x)^\frac12$.

Then divide both sides through by $s(x_i)$ (which has the same effect as pre-multiplying $y$ and $X$ by $K^{-1}$ where the diagonal of $K$ is $v(x_i)^\frac12$ in your approach) -- i.e. let $y^*_i = y_i/s(x_i)$, let $x^*_i= x_i/s(x_i)$ and let $\eta_i = \epsilon_i/s(x_i)$. Further, let $j^*_i = 1/s(x_i)$.

Then we have a new equation: $y^*_i = \beta_0 j^*_i + \beta_1 x^*_i + \eta_i$. The mutual independence of $\eta$ follows from the mutual independence of $\epsilon$ and the remaining properties of $\eta$ relating to mean and variance are readily established (the required variance follows from [basic properties of variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties)). Showing these results is, as they say in the books, left as an exercise for the reader.

This can be fitted using ordinary unweighted multiple linear regression by supplying $j^*$ and $x^*$ as predictors and $y^*$ as the response, but *note carefully that there's no intercept term here*.

The more general case of multiple regression $y=X\beta+\epsilon$ can be done in similar fashion, and here ii is convenient to proceed with matrices as you were doing, with similar effect -- you define $y^*$ as before and $X^*=W^\frac12 X$ for a diagonal weight-matrix $W$ where $w_i=\text{diag}(W)_i=1/v(x_i)$, noting that the corresponding column to the column of $1$'s in $X$ is not a constant in $X^*$ but of the same form as $j^*$ above.